# Is it possible to make @Transactional suspend function?

Tags: spring, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to rewrite my Vertx application using kotlin coroutines integration with Vertx.

I my application i'm using Spring Data JPA, so my Vertx verticles call to Spring services, whose methods are marked with `@Transactional` annotation using `Vertx.executeBlocking()`

Can I put `@Transactional` on kotlin `suspend` function?

Comment: If the class containing the suspend function is a Spring been, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the class containing the suspend function is a Spring bean then this is possible.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26705#issuecomment-816653989 "Coroutines transactions should be used with WebFlux and R2DBC, not WebMVC and JDBC."